# Streamlining Network Maintenance : Automated Remote Backups for Lenovo, Force10, and Dell Switches

Tags: switch, dell, hardware, force10, backups

***Can these switches be backed up automatically and pushed to a remote server via FTP?***

I attempt to find a way to automate the process of creating periodic backups of switches and sending them to a remote server via FTP. **I am interested in learning if it is possible to do so for the following switch models:**

- IBM/Lenovo G8052
- Force10 s55
- Dell s3048
- Dell s4048

I cannot find proper documentation about any of these systems and how to back up the systems or if it possible to automate the backup process.

> Is this possible for any of these systems?

> Is possible to automatically create backups of any of these switches and push them to a remote server via FTP?

> What is the process for that?

> Are there any alternatives or workarounds for achieving the desired result?

Comment: You can push backups from the devices, but you need to log into them to do it. You use a network management tool (recommendations are explicitly off-topic here) to do it for you. The tool logs into the device and pushes the configuration. The devices themselves do not do this.

Comment: _Some_ (not all) switches, e.g. H3C Comware, can run scheduled jobs that could include a configuration backup initiated from the device itself

Answer (score 2):

Legally required notice: I work for Dell.

This is how to do it on OS10: https://grantcurell.github.io/Backup%20OS10%20Config%20with%20Ansible/ using Ansible

### Playbook

```
---
- name: Setting up localhost for saving config
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Generating backup folder name in localhost
          set_fact:
             target_folder: "{{ backup_folder }}/{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}"
        - name: Create config_backup folder
          file:
            path: "{{ target_folder }}"
            state: directory
        - debug:
            msg: "Config files are to be backed up at {{target_folder}}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: True
- name: Backup os10 running configurations
  hosts: os10
  gather_facts: False
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch OS10 running configuration
      dellos10_command:
        commands: show running
      register: sh_runn
    - name: Save config to file
      copy:
        content: "{{ sh_runn.stdout | replace('\\n', '\n') }}"
        dest: "{{hostvars.localhost.target_folder}}/{{inventory_hostname}}_os10_show_run"
      delegate_to: localhost
    - debug:
        msg: "Config files are to be backed up at {{hostvars.localhost.target_folder}}"
      run_once: true
```

### Inventory

```
all:
  vars:
    backup_folder: "/root/backup"
  children:
    os10:
      hosts:
        192.168.1.169:
          ansible_become: 'yes'
          ansible_become_method: enable
          ansible_command_timeout: 120
          ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
          ansible_network_os: dellemc.os10.os10
          ansible_password: admin
          ansible_user: admin
        192.168.1.170:
          ansible_become: 'yes'
          ansible_become_method: enable
          ansible_command_timeout: 120
          ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
          ansible_network_os: dellemc.os10.os10
          ansible_password: admin
          ansible_user: admin
```

### Future Methods

I also put in a request with our product group recently to make it so that you could have a backup created on a remote target whenever a user enters configure mode. We're super early in that process and I didn't ask for a high priority so extremely rough estimate (don't hold me to it) is sometime next year for that.

### Other Vendors

Pretty much every network vendor supports Ansible these days so that would be my go to choice. Have the playbook launch via a cron job against your infrastructure and put it all in a timestamped backup folder on a remote target.

#### Minor Note

Dell bought Force10 so Force10 = Dell unless you mean the really old switches that are still branded as Force10 pre-acquisition.

Answer (score 1):

If these switches have command line interfaces (I believe they do) then a common way to take backups is via that command line interface by dumping out the equivalent of Cisco's `show running-config` command via SSH.

The traditional tool for automating this was [RANCID](https://shrubbery.net/rancid/), a more modern successor along the same lines is [Oxidized](https://github.com/ytti/oxidized/). Even more trendy yet is [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) which can be used for a variety of network device automation including backup.

To push config from the switch you should connect to the CLI and see if there are commands along the lines of `copy running-config tftp/sftp/ftp` (if, as you say, you can't lay hands on proper documentation you'll have to rely on some trial and error/built-in CLI documentation). Start with `copy ?` and see what options you are given, then try to follow your nose from there.

Comment: I am looking for a way to push backups from the switches to a remote server, not to pull them, for security reasons.

Comment: OK have amended the answer to add some stuff about copying configs from the command line. Not sure why that is necessarily any more secure than pulling them though.

Comment: @jrogers Just use a simple automation server to pull the configs using SSH, SFTP or SCP and put them on your backup server.